# Stripe Charges API - How to make test destination charge without Connect?

Tags: stripe-payments

Two parts to this question:

I only see docs about making Destination Charges when you're using Stripe Connect and Custom Accounts. Is it possible to do it without Connect?

If it's possible to make a destination charge with just regular (Standard?) Stripe Accounts, am I able to test it out without needing two accounts that are live?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destination Charges are charges made by a Connect Platform on behalf of a connected account (whether that connected account is a Standard, Express, or Custom account). There is no reason to make a Destination Charge without Connect (and indeed, no way that you could).

Comment: Ah okay, there were some places in the documentation where Connect wasn't specifically called out so I was unsure about it.

Thanks for clarifying taintedzodiac!